# java generics. [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, generics

I'm having truble with casting because of java generics. Can someone help?

```
Iterable<String> s = instance.outgoingEdges("Viseu");

    ArrayList<String> lf = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String x : s) {
        String[] array = (String[])instance.endVertices(x);
        for (Object v : array) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
```

The error comes in the following line:

```
String[] array = (String[])instance.endVertices(x);
```

Comment: Obviously endVertices doesn't return what you think it does. Show it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by generics.

The problem is simply that `endVertices()` is returning an `Object[]`, and you cannot cast an `Object[]` to a `String[]`.  Java won't let you.

If I understand the intent of that code, then I think you should change:

```
    String[] array = (String[]) instance.endVertices(x);
```

to

```
    Object[] array = (Object[]) instance.endVertices(x);
```

or maybe just

```
    Object[] array = instance.endVertices(x);
```